# Can I develop a hybrid native/HTML5 app for the Ubuntu Phone?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, html5, ubuntu-sdk

Can I develop a hybrid app that was used in conjunction with the native API and HTML5 in Ubuntu phone?

I know that it is possible to develop either native app or HTML5 app.

However, I want to know to develop a native app that has a HTML5 UI (hybrid) in Ubuntu Phone.

Comment: If you are referring to more than simply the QML based user interface, which Salem's answer addressed, there are hooks into native code via [Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) 
I'm still studying Cordova, so I don't have a complete answer for you, but, there is source to read/download here : https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-ubuntu.git;a=tree

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure what you mean with "hybrid" (a C++ app which displays an webapp? distribute app code between C++/QML/javascript? ), but you can use the WebView component to display a webpage/webapp on a qml application. This should work on Ubuntu Phone also.

Take this simple application composed by: "app.qml", "app.html" and "app.js" (yeah I know, this "application" is pretty lame...). This was only tested with `qmlviewer`, so if you try to run it through an IDE you probably will have to modify something in regard the relative paths used.

**app.qml**

```
import QtQuick 1.0
import QtWebKit 1.0

Rectangle {
        width: 800
        height: 600
        WebView {
                url: "app.html"
                anchors.fill: parent
                preferredWidth: 800
                preferredHeight: 600
                smooth: false
                settings.developerExtrasEnabled : true 
                settings.javascriptEnabled: true
        }
}
```

**app.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hi</title>
        <style>
        body {
                margin: 20px;
        }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
        <a href="#" id="test_me">Click me!</a>
</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var x = document.getElementById("test_me");
x.onclick = function(){
        console.log("Hi there");
        new_elem = document.createElement("h2");
        new_elem.textContent = "Hi there!";
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(new_elem);
};
```

Hope it helps.