# Debugging HTML5 With Ubuntu SDK

Tags: application-development, html5, sdk

I read this Question:
[Can I develop a hybrid native/HTML5 app for the Ubuntu Phone?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266260/can-i-develop-a-hybrid-native-html5-app-for-the-ubuntu-phone/319491#319491)

And it has a great answer, but that is no longer supported in the Ubuntu SDK (Ubuntu 13.04), now it uses:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1
import QtWebKit 3.0
```

And there are some errors when trying to call the "settings" of WebView:

```
Cannot assign to non-existent property "settings"
```

Digging in the web I found some solution, sadly doesn't work for me.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1
import QtWebKit 3.0
import QtWebKit.experimental 1.0

MainView {
// objectName for functional testing purposes (autopilot-qt5)
objectName: "mainView"
// Note! applicationName needs to match the .desktop filename 
applicationName: "Gastos"

width: units.gu(100)
height: units.gu(75)

Page {
    id: page
    title: "HTML5 App"

    Flickable {
        id: webViewFlickable
        anchors.fill: parent

        WebView {
            experimental.preferences.developerExtrasEnabled: true
            experimental.preferences.javascriptEnabled: true
            id: webView
            anchors.fill: parent
            url: "html/index.html"

            onTitleChanged: {
                page.title = title;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Some Warnings are shown but it starts well.

```
WARNING: This project is using the experimental QML API extensions for QtWebKit and is therefore tied to a specific QtWebKit release.

WARNING: The experimental API will change from version to version, or even be removed. You have been warned!
```

No developer tools though. Right click doesn't work, perhaps I'm missing something? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use WebKit's remote inspector.  Here's how I got it working in QtCreator 3.0:

- Download Google Chrome if you don't already have it.  (I believe Safari also works.)
- In QtCreator, click "Projects" in the left column, then click the "Run" tab at the top.
- Next to "Run Environment", click the "Details" drop-down.
- Click "Add" to add a new environment variable.
- Set a variable named **QTWEBKIT_INSPECTOR_SERVER** and set the value to any unused local port number, for example **9999**
- Run your project
- Open Chrome and enter the following URL: `http://127.0.0.1:9999`

It may take a moment to come up.  If the URL isn't working you can use a tool like Microsoft TCPView (on Windows) to make sure your process has the port open.

The trick to enabling the remote inspector in Qt comes from this post: https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-qt/2012-April/002646.html

Answer (score 5):

Starting with ubuntu-html5-theme package version 14.04.20140123-ppa2 (Trusty), one can launch the HTML5 app with the `--inspector` argument added. (This can be added to the `ubuntu-html5-app-launcher` command in the shell and by setting the run configuration in the SDK).

With the `--inspector` argument, the app's shell output shows an IP address and port. You can open this URL in a WebKit browser (chromium-browser, for example) and you will see an "inspectable view" that includes a JavaScript console that you can use to see warnings, errors, and to debug. This allows you to use browser-based HTML tools you may already be familiar with.

Here's an example launching the app from the shell:

```
$ ubuntu-html5-app-launcher --www=HTML5_APP_PROJECT_DIR --inspector
```

Here is the part of the output with the URL that you need to find:

```
Inspector server started successfully. Try pointing a WebKit browser to  http://192.168.1.105:9221
```

As noted, you can also configure the Ubuntu SDK to do the same thing. Check out the  Projects > Run Settings area and configure the Run Configuration like this:

[image]