# Debugging a pyqt5 Oxide(html) App

Tags: 14.04, qml, html5, pyqt

Based on this: [Debugging HTML5 With Ubuntu SDK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/319493/debugging-html5-with-ubuntu-sdk?rq=1)

For a PC pyqt5 qtwebkit app I can use the web inspector with chromium following theese steps:

First run in a terminal:

```
export QTWEBKIT_INSPECTOR_SERVER=127.0.0.1:9999
```

Then in the same terminal I run my app with:

```
python3 myApp.py --inspector
```

And It works very well for qtwebkit, Now I'm looking for a way to do this when my qml file uses oxide instead of qtwebkit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, just needed to add these lines to my .qml file

```
WebView {

    ...

    context: WebContext {
        devtoolsEnabled: true
        devtoolsPort: 9232
    }

    ...

}
```

From here:
[Enabling the devtools inspector when using Oxide in an Ubuntu SDK QML app](http://www.kryogenix.org/days/2014/12/30/enabling-the-devtools-inspector-when-using-oxide-in-an-ubuntu-sdk-qml-app/)